# Event.prevent() default ajax not sending data from form to php

Tags: php, html, ajax

I already checked around for this answer but all are different problems just same title (to prevent random duplicate marks).
Here is an ajax call to the click of the **filter** button that should send the data inserted in the form **formmatcat** to the php file **formfilt.php** and should load the result in a div with id **resultins**

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('#filter').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'formfilt.php',
            data: $('#formmatcat').serialize(),
            success: function () {        
                $("#resultins").load('formfilt.php');
            }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

I set the `preventdefault` to load only in the div without redirecting to the php file and this works but if I put the `preventDefault` it echoes the string I build by concatenating values sent from the form with those empty values. The strange thing is that if I remove `preventDefault` of course it redirects and loads the php file but with the correct values:

Moral of the story, data in the form with the ajax call goes correctly to the php file but looks like preventDefault don't let this. Thanks in advance

Here's the structure of the html part with the form

```
<form id="formmatcat" method="post" action="formfilt.php">  
.
.
various textboxes
.
.
</form>
```

Comment: is this function attached to a `submit` button or a standard `button`?

Comment: submit button inside the form

Comment: If it is a submit button try changing it to a standard button ie: `<input type='button' name='filter' id='filter' value='Filter' />` ~ also the `success` callback appears to reload the same page ~ it should populate the response into the div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing is sending an AJAX request to`formfilt.php`, when this call happens and it returns a response it will be stored as a parameter within the `success` or `$.done` function as I'll mention later, that is where your `echo`'d content will be.

What you're doing here is when the call is successful, you simple send a `GET` request to the same page. Since that `GET` request differs from the AJAX `POST` request and has no `POST` parameters you'll not get the correct output.

By simply submitting the form and letting it go to the page rather than cancelling the request you're getting the right values as you're directly posting to the page with the correct values, when you call the `load` function you're doing a seperate AJAX get request.

What [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) actually is, is a rough equivelant to `$.get` which is shorthand for `$.ajax`.

[Looking at jQuery AJAX docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> **jqXHR.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {});**
>   An alternative construct to the success callback option, the .done() method replaces the deprecated jqXHR.success() method. Refer to deferred.done() for implementation details.

Basically, a `$.ajax()` call returns a promise object that you can chain callbacks on when it is finished. Also note that `data` here will be the actual content within your PHP file, thus if you rewrite your AJAX call like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#filter').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'formfilt.php',
                data: $('#formmatcat').serialize()
            }).done(function(data) {
                $('#resultins').html(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

It will then continue to load the output of `formfilt.php` into the div with ID `resultins`.

Comment: Solved thanks , the problem was the .load , why didn't work and .html works? I did the same things on other forms with.load and it worked

Comment: `$.load` works but it applies a seperate request to the file, we're not using the ajax output from the actual first call before, and now we are - only difference ;)

Answer (score 0):

dont use form, use input without form, and use button tag use onclick to run function, if you use form, it will submit and redirect,
i'm not good with ajax on jQuery
but if i were to use javascript/XHR

```
var CB=document.getElementById("filter").value; //get input/filter value
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200)
        document.getElementById('contain').innerHTML=xhttp.responseText;
  };
var url="formfilt.php?filter="+CB;
xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xhttp.send();
```

if you want to use post :

```
xhttp.open("POST", "formfilt.php", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send('filter='+CB);
```

sorry, i'm also learning, and new to this, just learning a week ago,